# Reports by month with php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to know how to display report by month using PHP and Mysql

Example of Report on the web page:

```
January 2011
==============
Store  Name    |  Total Order Cost
SHOP A         |  £123 
SHOP B         |  £100

February 2011
==============
Store  Name    |  Total Order Cost
SHOP A         |  £123 
SHOP B         |  £100
SHOP C         |  £99.40
```

I have mysql tables

**tbl_shop**

- ShopID
- ShopName

**tbl_order**

- OrderID
- ShopID
- OrderDate
- Total

Comment: What exactly are you asking about How to write mysql query or How to display data with PHP?

Comment: @Shakti - Probably both.  @K102 - Group by ShopName? But what about the month

Comment: The best thing you can do is to try. After that, if you have problems, post your code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to iterate trough the result of the query and create an multidimensional array using the month/year combination as keys. The query below should be a good indication on how to fetch the required information from your database.

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(to.OrderDate), 
    YEAR(to.OrderDate), 
    SUM(to.Total), 
    to.* 
FROM tbl_order as to
INNER JOIN tbl_shop as ts ON ts.ShopID = to.ShopID
GROUP BY to.ShopID, MONTH(to.OrderDate), YEAR(to.OrderDate)
```

Note that I havn't tested this query - please handle it as pseudo-code. You might need to throw around the GROUP BY fields a little and test if it works.

Comment: Thank you. How to Specify Year and Month in your SQL? Eg April and 2011?

Comment: I assume OrderDate is an Datetime field in your table? Check out the MySQL Date functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: Thanks Wesley, I will give it a go! When it does show a report on the page - I want to be able to be able to highlight/disable/enable a row (shop name) which mean I have completed this process/task. What is the best way doing that? add a tbl_order.highlight ?

Comment: Is this array ok?         $report[2009][1][] = array(
            'Shop' => 'Shop Name',
            'Total' => 123,
        );

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT ShopName,SUM(Total),MONTHNAME(OrderDate) from tbl_shop
left join tbl_order
on tbl_shop.ShopID = tbl_order.ShopID
GROUP By(ShopID),MONTHNAME(OrderDate)
```

will give you All months report.

Comment: thank you, There should be a group by shop ID and SUM(tbl_order.Total) ?

Comment: Repeat the query? Why? Just add MONTHNAME(Orderdate) as a field you're selecting and group by ShopID, MONTHNAME(Orderdate). There's no need to execute that query multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT monthname(o.OrderDate) as Month, year(o.OrderDate) as Year,
  s.ShopName, sum(o.Total) as Total
FROM tbl_Shop s JOIN tbl_Order o
  ON s.ShopID=o.ShopID
GROUP BY o.shopID,year(o.Orderdate),month(o.Orderdate)
ORDER BY year(o.OrderDate),month(o.OrderDate)
```

then for every row from result if month+year has changed (a variable $last_date could help) then print

```
$Month $Year
==============
Store  Name    |  Total Order Cost
$ShopName      |  $Total
```

else print

```
$ShopName      |  $Total
```

Comment: how to recognize that month+year has been changed??